# How to add a section to a SitePrism page object dynamically?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, automated-tests, site-prism

I'm using SitePrism to test my web application. I have a number of classes that extend `SitePrism::Page` and a number of often-used HTML snippets are represented by matching classes extending `SitePrism::Section`

```
class Login < SitePrism::Section
  element :username, "#username"
  element :password, "#password"
  element :sign_in, "button"
end

class Home < SitePrism::Page
  section :login, Login, "div.login"
end
```

The problem is, the application I'm working on is based on a CMS, in which a page can be assembled by selecting a *Template* based on pre-defined content and then drag-and-dropping any number of available components onto the page.

The initial developers created a *Page Object* to mirror every available *Template*. This was fine as long as the number of tests was low and there weren't too many variants of pages that we had to test in our feature files.

With the addition of multiple test cases, the page objects started growing at an alarming rate.

While we can easily mitigate code duplication by defining *Sections* for every component available in the CMS and reusing them across *Page Objects*, there's just a lot of properties that rarely get used.

```
class BlogPost < SitePrism::Page

    section :logo, MySite::Components::Logo, '.logo'    
    section :navigation, MySite::Components::Navigation, '.primary-navigation'
    section :header, MySite::Components::BlogHeader, '.header'
    section :introduction, MySite::Components::Text, '.text .intro'
    # and so on, a lot of dynamic staff that could potentially be dropped onto the page
    # but does not neccessarily be there, going in dozens of lines
end
```

**Is there a way in SitePrism to dynamically add a section to an instance of a *Page Object* as opposed to a whole class?**

```
Then(/^Some step$/) do
    @blog = PageObjects::BlogPost.new()
    @blog.load("some url")
    @blog.somehow_add_a_section_here_dynamically
    expect (@blog.some_added_section).to be_visible
end
```

It also worries me that doing something like this would potentially cause CSS selectors to leak into the step definitions, which is generally a bad practice.

Another way to work around this would be to build *Page Objects* for specific examples of pages as opposed to the versatile templates. The *Template Page Objects* could just contain whatever's baked into the templates and be extended by other *Page Objects* that mirror specific pages, taking care of the differences. It sounds like a much cleaner approach so I'm probably going to write my tests this way

Anyway, the technical part of the question stands. Regardless of how good or bad an idea it is, how could I dynamically extend a page object with an additional section? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had at one point wanted to do what you're talking about for pretty much the same reason.  We had pages that could have new content-sections dragged into them; making them very dynamic.  I experimented with ways to do this and never found any that I particularly liked.

Methods like `element` and `sections` in site-prism each define a number of methods for the class.  You could call `MyPage.section` in your test or add a method that calls `self.class.section` and use that to add on new sections.  But those will exist for all instances of that page; probably not what you want.

You could alternatively tack them on to through the singleton_class:

```
my_page = MyPage.new
my_page.singleton_class.section(:new_section, NewSection, '#foo')
```

But that's getting a bit ugly to toss into your tests, right?

I've long thought that Sections should have a default_locator (but tough to get patches accepted)
With that we could generalize this a bit:

```
class DynamicSection < SitePrism::Section
  def self.set_default_locator(locator)
    @default_locator = locator
  end
  def self.default_locator
    @default_locator
  end
end      

class DynamicPage < SitePrism::Page
  # add sections (and related methods) to this instance of the page
  def include_sections(*syms)
    syms.each do |sym|
      klass = sym.to_s.camelize.constantize
      self.singleton_class.section(sym, klass, klass.default_locator)
    end
  end
end
```

And then you can use these as the parents.

```
class FooSection < DynamicSection
  set_default_locator '#foo'
  element :username, "#username"
end

class BlogPostPage < DynamicPage
  # elements that exist on every BlogPost
end
```

In the tests:

```
@page = BlogPostPage.new
@page.include_sections(:foo_section, :bar_section)
expect(@page.foo_section).to be_visible
```

On the other-hand it really might be easier to just create a few different variations of the page-object for use in tests.  (Are you really going to test that many variations?  Maybe..maybe not.)

Comment: As mentioned in the question itself. I'm more inclined to follow the _page object per page_ pattern as opposed to _page object per template_. I'll just leave the templates as base classes or mixins. I was just curious how this could be done in terms of meta-programming in Ruby.

Comment: It turned out to be fun and interesting to re-visit this problem; so I'm glad you asked it :-)  I might include something like this on my fork going forward.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a section to just a page object instance by modifying its singleton class.

```
Then(/^Some step$/) do
  @blog = PageObjects::BlogPost.new
  @blog.load("some url")

  # You can see that @blog does not have the logo section
  expect(@blog).not_to respond_to(:logo)

  # Add a section to just the one instance of BlogPost
  class << @blog
    section(:logo, MySite::Components::Logo, '.logo')
  end

  # You can now see that #blog has the logo section
  expect(@blog).to respond_to(:logo)
end
```

This will likely result in duplicate the section definition in multiple steps. To address this, you could create a method within the `BlogPost` to dynamically add the specified sections.

In the following `BlogPost` class, a dictionary of available components is created. The class has a method that adds components based on the dictionary definition.

```
class BlogPost < SitePrism::Page
  COMPONENT_DICTIONARY = {
    logo: {class: MySite::Components::Logo, selector: '.logo'},
    navigation: {class: MySite::Components::Navigation, selector: '.primary-navigation'},
    header: {class: MySite::Components::BlogHeader, selector: '.header'}
  }

  def add_components(*components)
    Array(components).each do |component|
      metaclass = class << self; self; end
      metaclass.section(component, COMPONENT_DICTIONARY[component][:class], COMPONENT_DICTIONARY[component][:selector])
    end
  end
end
```

As an example of the usage:

```
# Create a blog post that just has the logo section
@blog = BlogPost.new
@blog.add_components(:logo)

# Create a blog post that has the navigation and header section
@blog2 = BlogPost.new
@blog2.add_components(:navigation, :header)

# Notice that each blog only has the added components
expect(@blog).to respond_to(:logo)
expect(@blog).not_to respond_to(:navigation)
expect(@blog).not_to respond_to(:header)

expect(@blog2).not_to respond_to(:logo)
expect(@blog2).to respond_to(:navigation)
expect(@blog2).to respond_to(:header)
```

Comment: Neat, going to try this out tomorrow.

Comment: Justin, you posted while I was still typing, but it looks like we have very similar ideas here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use page.find for that purpose

```
class MyPage < SitePrism::Page
  element :static_selector_element, "#some-static-id"
  def dynamic_element(id)
    find "label[for=\"dynamic-value-#{id}\"]"
  end
end
```

in your test:

```
RSpec.feature 'My Feature' do
  scenario 'Success' do
    p = MyPage.new 
    p.visit '/'
    p.static_selector_element.click
    p.dynamic_element(SomeObject.fist.id).click
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I needed.